# Convert literal to associated type in generic struct implementation

Tags: generics, rust, type-conversion, associated-types

How can I convert 0.0 or any other number to the associated Item type in an Iterator assuming that the associated type has the proper trait bound? The following code describes my attempt.

```
use num::Float;
use std::iter::Iterator;

pub struct Signal<S>
    where S: Iterator, S::Item: Float
{
    signal: S,
    val: S::Item,
}

impl<S> Signal<S>
    where S: Iterator, S::Item: Float
{
    pub fn new(signal: S) -> Self {
        Signal {
            signal: signal,
            val: S::Item::from(0.0),
        }
    }
}
```

I am currently getting the error: expected associated type, found floating-point variable

Answer (score 2):

[`NumCast::from`](https://docs.rs/num/0.2.0/num/cast/trait.NumCast.html#tymethod.from) seems to be the best match. I recommend not importing it because the method name conflicts with the widely used one, `From::from`.

```
use num::Float;
use std::iter::Iterator;

pub struct Signal<S>
    where S: Iterator, S::Item: Float
{
    signal: S,
    val: S::Item,
}

impl<S> Signal<S>
    where S: Iterator, S::Item: Float
{
    pub fn new(signal: S) -> Self {
        Signal {
            signal: signal,
            val: num::NumCast::from(0.0).unwrap(),
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`Float`](https://docs.rs/num/0.2.0/num/trait.Float.html) trait doesn’t provide a `from({float}) -> Self` operation.  But it does depend on [`NumCast`](https://docs.rs/num/0.2.0/num/trait.NumCast.html):

```rs
use num::{Float, NumCast};
…
val: NumCast::from(0.0).unwrap(),
```

and also on [`Zero`](https://docs.rs/num/0.2.0/num/trait.Zero.html):

```rs
use num::{Float, Zero};
…
val: S::Item::zero(),
```